# Infinite loop while switch button isChecked

Tags: android, kotlin

I am fairly new to kotlin and was wondering if there was to infinitely run a loop when a switch button is in the isChecked state. My code is as follows :

```
binding.switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->

        if(isChecked) {
            P1 = true
            try {
                while(P1) {
                    for (i in 0..10) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "The iterator number is $i")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Hii")

            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                // break while loop

            } catch(e: NullPointerException){

            }
        }
```

While the button is in the isChecked state, I want the loop to continuously loop the for loop.
Thankyou in advance for the help!1

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, when i press the switch, app just freezes. This switch is in the MainUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs when one process block the MAIN thread (or UI thread) the name of problem is [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr?hl=pt-br), to solve this, you can run this process in another thread(ex: [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?hl=pt-br)).

example :

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
  try {
    while(true) {
       //the logic here 
    }
  } catch (e: NullPointerException) {}
 }
```

But, be careful when you access the view components in this thread because need a little treatment for this.

Comment: This will run forever and leak anything referenced inside the coroutine every time the activity or fragment is recreated. You need to either use `lifecycleScope` or store a reference to the CoroutineScope you’re creating and cancel it when the Activity or Fragment View is destroyed. Also, a coroutine needs to use `while(isActive)` instead of `while(true)` to be able to cancel it.